# How exactly to set clientIds and audiences to authenticate Google Cloud Endpoints for an Android App

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

In the endpoints App Engine backend, how exactly do I set

```
@Api(name=...
     clientIds = {what-goes-here-exactly-1},
     audiences = {what-goes-here-exactly-2}
)
```

and in the Android client, how exactly do I set

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this,
           what-goes-here-exactly-3);
```

There are conflicting/confusing/unclear instructions here http://devthots.blogspot.com/  and here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android#making-authenticated-calls

I've generated lots of keys in my API Console's API Access, but not sure how to use them and  append/prepend them for use in the above statements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your backend you would include:

```
@Api(
  name = "myapi",
  version = "v1",
  clientIds = {Ids.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Ids.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID},
  audiences = {Ids.ANDROID_AUDIENCE}
)
```

Where those constants are defined as something like:

```
public class Ids {
  public static final String WEB_CLIENT_ID = "12345.apps.googleusercontent.com";
  public static final String ANDROID_CLIENT_ID = "12345-abc.apps.googleusercontent.com";
  public static final String ANDROID_AUDIENCE = WEB_CLIENT_ID;
}
```

Using the above values, the code you would use in your Android code is:

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this,
    "server:client_id:" + Ids.ANDROID_AUDIENCE);
```

Comment: Thanks Dan.  It might be clearer to say  credential=GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this,"server:client_id:" + Ids.WEB_CLIENT_ID) in your answer instead.  Can you update?  I think this is solving my problem, but I'm still having a little difficulty getting it to work in local dev server mode, then I'll accept the answer.

Comment: To make it more understandable, it's actually ANDROID_AUDIENCE, they just happen to be equivalent.